# Convert Firestore value changes to Typescript object

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have the interfaces:

```
interface Item {
    data: string
}

interface Test {
    item: Item
    url: string
}
```

My data in Firestore is stored as follows

```
Collection Tests
    id: {
        item: {
            data: "some data"
        },
        url: "abc.com",
    }
}
```

How can I type the incoming objects on a collection read?

```
this.db.collection('tests').valueChanges().subscribe(tests => {
    // Do some sort of type conversion
});
```

Or better yet could I do something like this:

```
this.db.collection('tests').valueChanges().subscribe<Test[]>(tests => {
    tests[0].url // valid typescript
});
```

Comment: So, to be clear, are you saying that your document contains an object type field named `item` which has a string property called `data`?

Comment: The documents field `item` is a Firestore Map with a key `data`

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

According to [this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md) the simplest way to achieve a typed result is by adding the type after `collection`

```
this.db.collection<Test>('tests').valueChanges().subscribe(tests => {
    // ....
});
```

**Old Answer**

This is the only solution I have come up with, but I am looking for something more readable

```
    this.db.collection('tests').valueChanges().pipe(
        map(tests => {
            return tests as Test[];
        })
    ).subscribe(fs_tests => {
        // ....
    });
```

Comment: If you just want a straight cast (assuming that the document always exactly matches your interfaces), it's not going to get any simpler than this.